# Convert a WPF into a PNG file with C#

Tags: c#, wpf, png, screenshot

I would like to convert the WPF display into a PNG file.

This is being used to create an invoice for a holiday. The code I currently have creates the PNG file but it creates a blank document.
Here is what I am trying to do:

```
 var screenCap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)this.Width, (int)this.Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);

 var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
 var outputScreen = BitmapFrame.Create(screenCap);
 encoder.Frames.Add(outputScreen);

 using (var file = File.OpenWrite(@"Invoice.png"))
 {
     encoder.Save(file);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call screenCap.Render(this) after you've constructed the object, but before you call BitmapFrame.Create(screenCap)

Comment: That was perfect mate! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The following code will capture a specified element from the display and write it to a specified path:

```
private void SaveImage(FrameworkElement targetElement, string savePath)
{
    var bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)targetElement.ActualWidth, (int)targetElement.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);

    bmp.Render(targetElement);

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();

        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmp));
        encoder.QualityLevel = 100;
        encoder.Save(stream);

        File.WriteAllBytes(savePath, stream.ToArray());
    }
}
```